# Is it possible to get the url of the user friends in LinkedIn?

Tags: android

Actually I want to retrieve the URL of the user's Friends of a LinkedIn profile.
Is it possible to get it any how?

Answer (score 0):

you can go to the profile of the related person and simple check his id in the url. or copy the url.
for eg:: https://www.linkedin.com/profile/view?id=280044840 where id is the user's name